# Too low speed with implemented speed test in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, flutter

I try to implement a speedtest by downloading a file in Android via http. My results are always around 30 Mbps although Ookla speedtest measures 60-100 Mbps. The file size is 100 MB. I have tried a few sources which should provide enough bandwidth.

```
public void run() {
    long count = 0;
    long start = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long end;
    try {
        InputStream in = new URL("source").openStream();
        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        start = System.nanoTime();
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 2048)) != -1) {
            count += 2048;
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    } finally {
        end = System.nanoTime();
    }

    System.out.println(count / 125000);
    System.out.println(end - start);
    System.out.println((count / 125000.0) / ((end - start) / 1000000000.0));
}
```

EDIT: I set a limit of 15 Mbit/s for my smartphone and now the algorithm works without problems... but I still don't know why it only captures up to 30 Mbps with a bandwidth below 100 Mbps . It can't really be a performance problem, since it captures 150 Mbps at 1Gbps bandwidth.

Comment: Ookla probably assumes you want to know how your actual speed compares to what your internet provider advertises. But what does your internet provider count in its measurements? I'm actually not sure, but you can bet they (and Ookla too) count every bit sent, including all the lower layer (TCP headers, IP headers, link-layer, etc) headers. You're only measuring the TCP payload and ignoring all the rest. However, for a large file and a typical network configuration I would only expect the difference to be a few percent, not 100%, so in the end I don't really know why the difference is so large.

Comment: Thx for the answer. You're right, and I wouldn't have been surprised at a smaller deviation. However, the test seems to measure relatively accurately, but no longer from 30 Mbps. As if that were an upper bound in Android. I also implemented it in Dart with the same result.

Comment: `count += 2048;` That should be `count += bytesRead;` Take a larger buffer like 8192.

Comment: I know. I changed that because I thought that might be the error. But that would at most correct the result downwards and not upwards. I'll try a larger buffer

Comment: Try wrapping in a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :) I have now changed the addition to `count += bytesRead` and wrapped the `InputStream` into a `BufferedinputStream`. Still identical results are coming.